# Hiding Asp.Net user control using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I want to know if I could hide/show an asp user control when pressing a button in another user control on the same master page?

Answer (score 3):

The `Visible` property will do this for you. The Click handler on your Button would be something like:

```
protected void ToggleButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TargetControl.Visible = !TargetControl.Visible;
}
```

Comment: thanks Justin but I think that will be done correctly if the button is on the master page not on **another** user control

Comment: @moses, what's the problem of adapting the code to your needs? Justin showed you exactly the way, you just need to replace "TargetControl" with a control you need. What exactly is your problem? Googling on how to find a control in asp.net takes about 1min if you're really slow. If you're fast, it's a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

if you have got 2 `users controls` in same page . you can use this code :

in usercontrol 1

```
<asp:button Text="hide" runat="server" ID="B1" OnClick="HideOtherUserControl" />
```

and in code-behind

```
 protected void HideOtherUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent.FindControl("WebUserControl1").Visible = false;
    }
```